# AccountManager IllegalArgumentException: key is null

Tags: java, android, accountmanager, accounts

Ok, I'm getting an `IllegalArgumentException` at a point where it shouldn't.

I have a custom extension of `Account` that is saved using the AccountManager:

```
// Method inside a custom extension of Account
public boolean save(AccountManager manager) {
    removeAll(manager);
    boolean result = manager.addAccountExplicitly(this, null, toBundle());
    manager.setUserData(this, KEY_1, value1);
    manager.setUserData(this, KEY_2, value2);
    manager.setUserData(this, KEY_3, value3);
    return result;
}
```

The keys are constant String values but app still throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key is null
```

I have to say that I'm only attaching the user data in this fashion because using:

```
 manager.addAccountExplicitly(this, null, toBundle());
```

didn't seem to attach the values. Do the keys require a special name pattern?

Anybody had this problem before?

---

**Update:**

It gets thrown inside the `manager.setUserData()` which looks like this (Android code):

```
public void setUserData(final Account account, final String key, final String value) {
    if (account == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("account is null");
    if (key == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("key is null");
    try {
        mService.setUserData(account, key, value);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // won't ever happen
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

When I "walk" into this method with eclipse I get this in the debug perspective:

[image]

The values aren't null >o<

Comment: Which line is the error on? Print out all the arguments you pass it just before you call it.

Comment: Where *exactly* is the exception being thrown?

Comment: Updated the question with the info requested

Comment: Can you please post the entire exception with line numbers?  It should be in your logcat output.

Comment: I think something is leading to null, check the line that throws exception. is it leading to account null or key null?

Comment: I don't have access to the project now but the exception is clear from the code where it is thrown (hint: "key is null"). But the thing that puzzles me is that before using the `setUserData` method I was providing the userData with the method `toBundle()` but when retrieving the userData I got null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after further research into [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android)'s `AccountManager` I did not find a way to make it work like I was trying but I found a solution.

Instead of saving the details as an user data bundle I save them as `authToken` values using the key as the `authTokenType` like this:

```
public boolean save(AccountManager manager) {
    removeAll(manager);
    boolean result = manager.addAccountExplicitly(this, null, toBundle());
    manager.setAuthToken(this, KEY_1, value1);
    manager.setAuthToken(this, KEY_2, value2);
    manager.setAuthToken(this, KEY_3, value3);
    return result;
}
```

And then retrieving the values like this:

```
value1 = manager.peekAuthToken(account, KEY_1);
```

I'm still not sure if this is the way to store data for an `Account` but it's the only one I've managed to make work so far.